# Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

Line 18: $('#display-month').html(msg); within the get_month() function is returning the following error: Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

I initially fire get_month() on load, to load the current month calendar into .

I do not know why that line is interrupting loading the current month calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  function get_month()
  {
    var u = $("#days_for_month_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      ajax : '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: u,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        $('#display-month').html(msg);

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;
  }

  get_month();

  $("a.view_events").live('click', function() {

    var date = $(this).data('date');

    // change if URL changes
    var u = $("#events_for_day_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      year : $(this).data('year'),
      month : $(this).data('month'),
      day : $(this).data('day'),
      date : $(this).data('date'),
      ajax : '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: u,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        $('#display-events').html(msg);
        $('#display-event_detail').html('');

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-events


  $("a.view_event_details").live('click', function() {

    var u = $("#event_detail_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      event_id : $(this).data('event_id'),
      ajax : '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: u,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        $('#display-event_detail').html(msg);
        $('#display-events').html('');

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view_event_details


  $("a.month_link").live('click', function() {

    $('#display-events').html('');

    var u = $("#days_for_month_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      month_url : $(this).data('month_url'),
      ajax : '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: u,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        $('#display-month').html(msg);

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-month

 $("a.view_subscriptions").live('click', function() {

    var u = $("#subscriptions_url").attr("href");

    var form_data = {
      ajax : '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: u,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        $('#display-subscriptions').html(msg);
        //$('#display-subscriptions').toggle();

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-subscriptions

 $("#update_subscriptions").live('click', function() {

    var u = $("#update_subscriptions_url").attr("href");

    var vals = []
    $('input:checkbox[name="calendar[]"]').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            vals.push(this.value);
        }
    });

    var form_data = {
      ajax : '1',
      calendar: vals,
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: u,
      data: form_data,
      success: function( msg ) {

        get_month();
        $('#display-subscriptions-update').html(msg).fadeOut(6000);
        $('#display-subscriptions').html('');

      } // end success

    }); // end ajax

    return false;

  }); // end on.click view-subscriptions

}); // end document ready
```

UPDATE: validated the html it returned in the ajax calls (that did not cause the problem) and I added dataType: 'html' to the ajax call, which fixed it.

Comment: Comment chunks of code out until the problem goes away. Once it does,  you know exactly what part caused the problem.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`.